# ESP8266 SPI pinout

Tags: spi, esp8266

I'm new to the whole development board thing and I've just started experimenting with an ESP8266-12E module.

Unfortunately I am unable to get the SPI display working. It works on an Arduino UNO, so I guess my code is alright. I think that it have something to do with the way I'm connecting the display to the ESP.

According to the following pictures there seems to be multiple SPI lines `5,6,7,16` and `14,10,9,13,11,12`. Which ones are the right ones for me to use?

[image: ESP-12E schema]

Comment: *It works on an Arduino UNO, so my code is alright* So you're assuming that since your code works on an Arduino it will also work immediately on a **completely different processor platform** as well ? You obviously have a lot to learn...

Comment: I do have a lot to learn, thats why I'm asking such a banal question. You don't have to be so touchy about it. Just keep on reading if you dont have anything smart to say.. I thought the platforms were compatible because I can programm my ESP from Arduino IDE. I'm sorry that I don't initially know everything when engaging with something new. The main problem is, that I don't understand the pinouts on the ESP. If I would know where the SPI lines are, I could verify myself if the code is right or not.

Comment: Don't be deterred by negative comments, WE ALL HAD TO START SOMEWHERE, and the pinout could be confusing if you don't know what HSPI means ... keep asking questions and don't be afraid to admit you don't know something, because at one point we were all in the same boat.  This community is meant for support, not for dogging others who ask questions they can't figure out the answer to own their own.  Best of luck to you.

Comment: Here's the technical reference for ESP8266 that was very helpful for me when learning about the ESP8266 https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp8266-technical_reference_en.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use 14,10,9,13 for SPI, the other pins represent HSPI Host Multi-device SPI the mapping according to this discussion is [HSPI mapping confusion](http://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?t=1213)

```
MTDO > CS
MTCK > MOSI
MTDI > MISO
MTMS > CLK
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ones labeled HSPI, reason being ...

The ESP8266 has 17 GPIO pins (0-16), however, you can only use 11 of them, because 6 pins (GPIO 6 - 11) are used to connect the flash memory chip If you try to use one of these pins, you might crash your program.

GPIO 1 and 3 are used as TX and RX of the hardware Serial port (UART), so in most cases, you can’t use them as normal I/O while sending/receiving serial data.

In regards to the NodeMCU (esp8266 dev board), this is true as well:
https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/spi/

I strongly recommend reading this document:
https://tttapa.github.io/ESP8266/Chap01%20-%20ESP8266.html

https://www.esp8266.com/wiki/lib/exe/detail.php?id=esp8266_gpio_pin_allocations&media=pin_functions.png

[image: ESP8266 PIN Functions]